# Sorting category posts in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to got my products base on category `I've done that` now I want show each category in different row(design matter) which i have to use `take` `offset` and `limit`. and that would work also.

**The problem is to sorting these results.**

## This is what it supposed to be as result:

[image: screen1]

## Here is the code i use:

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
            $category = DB::table('subcategories')
            ->join('admin_designs', 'admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
            ->join('products', function ($join) {
              $join->on('subcategories.id', '=', 'products.subcategory_id');
            })->take(1)->get();

            $categorytwo = DB::table('subcategories')
            ->join('admin_designs', 'admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
            ->join('products', function ($join) {
              $join->on('subcategories.id', '=', 'products.subcategory_id');
            })->offset(1)->limit(9)->get();

            $view->with('category', $category);
            $view->with('categorytwo', $categorytwo);
        });
```

> The issue now is that the result will be mix from all categories
>   instead of being separated.

**BUT**

## If I have this kind of code:

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
            $category = DB::table('subcategories')
            ->join('admin_designs', 'admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
            ->join('products', function ($join) {
              $join->on('subcategories.id', '=', 'products.subcategory_id');
            })->get();

            $view->with('category', $category);
        });
```

and using in blade such as:

```
@foreach($category->groupby('category_id') as $key => $value)
  @foreach($value as $ki)
    product title{{$ki->title}}, Category id: {{$key}}, Subcategory id: {{$ki->subcategory_id}}<br>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> Then it will show the result seperatly base on their category id, the
>   only issue with this is that i cannot get my result as `->take('1')` post +
>   `->offset('1')->take('9')`.

any idea?

Comment: " get my result as take1 =  take9 "  what do u mean ?

Comment: @Itisallyours look at my photo at the top then my first query, `take('1)` and in second query `offset('1')->take('9')`